# Passing javascript variables from one file to another

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to pass the 'custCenter' object from this javascript file to another one. I have made it a global variable but am not sure how to access it from another javascript file:

```
var map = null;
var markers = [];
var custCenter = {};

function initMap()
{
    var startingCenter = { lat: 49.22, lng: -122.66 };
    custCenter = { lat: 49.22, lng: -122.66 };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: custCenter,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
    map.addListener('click', function (event) {
        var myLatLng = event.latLng;

        deleteMarkers();
        addMarker(myLatLng);

        window.lat = myLatLng.lat();
        window.lng = myLatLng.lng();
        alert(window.lat + ', ' + window.lng);  
    });

    // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
    addMarker(custCenter);
}

// Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) 
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map                
    });            

    markers.push(marker);
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map); 
    }
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
}
```

This is for an app that I am making to help people find their lost pets. The custCenter object is the lat and lng that the user clicks on google maps, which I want to pass to another JS file linked to an html using google maps. Here is the app if you would like to see: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/tom/getlocation.html

Comment: Are you including both JavaScript files in the HTML document? I can only see the getLoc.js in the HTML document. These are in the global scope and you should be able to access the object from either script.

Comment: Are you loading a new page?

Comment: @valarauko yes I will be loading this page: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/ , and would like the center on this page to be the coordinates selected by the user on the page in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your second script tag is included after this one so that the `custCenter` variable it depends on will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the page which would clear all variables set by the previous page (it has no memory between pages). To pass the values to the other page, you would need to make use of local or session storage or cookies, you set the value on the first page

```
sessionStorage.setItem("custCenter", JSON.stringify(custCenter))
```

And then load it at the beginning of the second page

```
custCenter = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("custCenter"))
```

Comment: Well right now I have it to load a new page. But I am using AngularJS so would there be a way I could do it without loading a new page, maybe using ngRoute? And storing the variable using the $http service?

Comment: Im not very familiar with angular, but according to the docs you said, ngroute and $http would be good, you could pass the parameters to the route, I think it would be more appropiate

Comment: Using the $routeParams service? That would be perfect but from the book I'm reading it looks like those parameters have to be specified as a value in the url, i'm not seeing how you could pass in a dynamic variable that was selected by the user.

Comment: No, you would need to configure the routes with routeProvider, in order to be able to declare dynamic url's, then you can define a route for example /foo/:custCenter, then you can trigger $location.path('/foo/' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(custCenter)));